# Setting the width of the cells in html5

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to attribute an width for cells but it doesn't work. I used CSS to make it, since  width is not supported in HTML5. In my problem I have a table with headers and inside that table I have another table with a scroll to show the results, I need to order the cell results by the headers attributing the same width as headers. Can someone help me? 
Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fh7jsoec/1/) . Thank you!

Here's what i've tried:

```
<table class="two">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th style="width:150px">Tipo de Anúncio</th>
                    <th style="width:150px">Tipo de Imóvel</th>
                    <th style="width:150px">Localização</th>
                    <th style="width:150px">Mediador</th>
                    <th style="width:150px">Preço</th>
                    <th style="width:150px">Área</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody class="scroll">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <div class="scroll">
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="width:150px">January</td>
                                    <td style="width:150px">$100</td>
                                    <td style="width:150px">February</td>
                                    <td style="width:150px">$80</td>
                                    <td style="width:150px">February</td>
                                    <td style="width:150px">$80</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>February</td>
                                    <td>$80</td>
                                    <td>February</td>
                                    <td>$80</td>
                                    <td>February</td>
                                    <td>$80</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>January</td>
                                    <td>$100</td>
                                    <td>February</td>
                                    <td>$80</td>
                                    <td>February</td>
                                    <td>$80</td>
                                </tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several problem in your layout but the main is  not the width but the colspan : (thw width work right) 
your `th` don't wrap all the column. If ypu have six column you need a colspan = 6

```
<tbody class="scroll">
    <tr>
     <td colspan="6">
```

I have touched only few element but ypou can see a preliminary result [in this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/udrcttsp/)